# input me muestra parte del un texto traido de sql

Tags: php, html, sql

Tengo la siguiente linea de codigo:

```html
<input type="text" id="carrera" name="pertenece" placeholder="pertenece" value=<?= $nombre['nombre']?>>
```

Les cuento que tengo un formulario donde traigo los datos para que el usuario pueda editarlos, uno de los valores que quiero mostrar me muestra solo una palabra "Profesorado"...  al inspeccionar veo el valor del value y me muestra así:

[image: resultado]

Es decir que la consulta en SQL me trae toda la frase "Profesorado de educación primaria" pero me muestra solo la primer palabra. ¿Por qué puede suceder?

Comment: Prueba usando las comillas hasta el final de la frase: `value="Profesorado de educación primaria"`.

Comment: Hace falta ver cómo se construye ese elemento `input`. Copia y pega el texto de tu código, no subas imágenes. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. También puedes leer [mre]. Saludos

Comment: tienes que mostrar el codigo php con el que armas el input y tambien el dato como esta guardado en la base de datos, lo que muetras no ayuda de nada.

Answer (score 0):

Esto se debe a que no estas poniendo las comillas en el atributo value de tu elemento:
pasa de esto:

```
<input type="text" id="carrera" name="pertenece" placeholder="pertenece" value=<?= $nombre['nombre']?>>
```

a esto:

```
<input type="text" id="carrera" name="pertenece" placeholder="pertenece" value="<?= $nombre['nombre']?>">
```

Al ser, tu resultado, mas de una palabra debería de estar encapsulado entre comillas.